# Why I do not have access rights on the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I use [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) in local - alright.

On the server however, it issues the followed error, and I cannot figure out what how to gain access.

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view
>   this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Comment: Nor can we seeing as you haven't given us a even vague clue, of what you are accessing from where, and what it needs access to...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Maybe you should [enable remote access](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages)

```
<elmah>  
    <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />  
</elmah>
```

Comment: is this setting for elmah MVC or the earlier version?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to archil's answer, don't forget that if you require authentication, the allowed users and roles are case sensitive:

```
<appSettings>
    ...
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false"/>
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false"/>
    <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="true"/>
    <add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false"/>
    <!-- The roles and usernames for elmah are case sensitive! -->
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="Administrator"/>
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="user1,user2,user3"/>
    <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah"/>
    ...
</appSettings>
```